# UserUpdateInfo undefined name 'user'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Due to updating Firebase auth I need to change some deprecated code.
I have seen on the Migration guide that:

****BREAKING**: Removed the UpdateUserInfo class when using updateProfile in favor of named arguments.**

I've updated it for the most part however I am still getting an error.

```
// Update the username
await updateUserName(name, authResult.user);
return authResult.user.uid;
```

}

```
Future updateUserName(String name, User currentUser) async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: user.displayName);
```

}

Error = Undefined name 'user'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to use the `currentUser` parameter by name instead of `user`.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: currentUser.displayName);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that seems to have resolved the error